# How to programmatically invoke "Add all ambiguous imports" action/quick fix

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a custom action which changes the text of a file. After that action has been triggered I would like to programmatically invoke the action/quick fix "Add all unambigious imports" I do not want to have the popup, I want just the action to be triggered silently. I can not find the action or quick fix to run against.

Answer (score 0):

you might try to create a macro for this and see if that does what you want. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html. I'm not sure if the macro will run without the popup.

Please let me know if this is usefull.

-Kaj :)

Comment: Appreciate you trying, however this is exactly what I am trying to avoid, I have a custom action that I may run 100 times across 100s of files and I do not want to have to manually click anything.

Comment: Thanks :) I see. What about creating a macro that first run your custom action and then run "Add all unambigious imports"?

btw: You can configure save actions using the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions and that can also be usefull to automate things sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `JavaCodeStyleManager.getInstance(project).optimizeImports(file);`